# flask-migrate / alembic: How to add a postgresql identity column to an existing table?

Tags: python, postgresql, alembic, flask-migrate

I’m trying to create a migration to add a new [identity column](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#postgresql-10-and-above-identity-columns) to an existing table. The table should eventually become the new primary key of that table.

```py
class Action(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.Identity(), primary_key=True)  # new primary key
    uuid = db.Column(sqlalchemy_utils.UUIDType, index=True, nullable=False)  # old primary key
```

When I generate the migration using `flask db migrate` I only get a new integer column:

```py
def upgrade():
    """Upgrade from previous version."""
    op.add_column("actions", sa.Column("id", sa.Integer(), nullable=False))
```

For a new sequence based id-column I know that I would need to create the sequence explicitly to use it as `server_default` (eg as described here: https://sqlalchemy-alembic.narkive.com/U6p0nSGQ/adding-an-auto-increment-column-to-an-existing-table):

```py
def upgrade():
    """Upgrade from previous version."""
    op.execute(sa.schema.CreateSequence(sa.Sequence("actions_id_seq")))
    op.add_column("actions", sa.Column("id", sa.Integer(), server_default=sa.text("nextval('actions_id_seq'::regclass)"), nullable=False))
```

This is using sqlalchemy 1.4.42 and alembic 1.8.1.

I couldn’t find any way to add an identity column with `GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY`. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was as simple as adding `sa.Identity()`:

```py
def upgrade():
    """Upgrade from previous version."""
    op.add_column("actions", sa.Column("id", sa.Integer(), sa.Identity(), nullable=False))
```